# User.Identity.Name is different before and after publishing to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I am using @User.Identity.Name in my Asp.net mvc web application. This is shown as Domain\user on local and user@domain.com on azure site once deployed. Instead of using @User.Identity.Name, is there any way to make it unique on local and server. I have many code breaking areas due to this conflict.

**I added Azure active directory authentication to my application which is hosted on Azure.**

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
   var displayName = principal?.DisplayName;
}
```

this displayName is shown on local and once published to Azure it is like null "". What would be the best way to show display name on Azure server once published?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using the AD libraries for traditional on-premise AD. To program against Azure AD , you could use OpenID Connect to authenticate users from an Azure AD tenant. Please see the code sample below :

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect

To get the display name of the current user , you could try :

```
var displayName = ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "name").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

If you also want to show Domain\DisplayName when using Azure AD , you could get domain name by :

```
var domian= ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value.Split('@')[1].ToString();
```